# How do I resolve Invalid URI error when using Powershell to download TFS file

Tags: powershell, tfs

I have a powershell script to download items from a TFS directory.

The code is as follows:

```
$TfsWorkspace = "$/Region/Application/Master/Payments"
$TfsUri = "http://tfs.company.net:8080/tfs/global"
$LocalDir = "C:\Deployment\"

Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.TeamFoundation.PowerShell

# Connect to TFS
$TFSServer = Get-TfsServer -Name $TfsUri

# Get all directories and files in the $TfsWorkspace directory
$items = Get-TfsChildItem $TfsWorkspace -Recurse -Server $TFSServer

$tfsCollection = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TfsTeamProjectCollection -ArgumentList $TfsUri
$tfsVersionControl = $tfsCollection.GetService([Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.VersionControlServer])

# Download each item to a specific destination
foreach ($item in $items) 
{

    #If it finds a folder create the folder first
    if ($item.ItemType -eq "Folder") 
    {
        $newFolder = ($LocalDir + $([IO.Path]::GetFullPath($item.ServerItem.Remove(0,1)).Remove(0,3)))
        New-Item -ItemType directory -Path $($newFolder) -Force
    }
    else 
    {
        $newFile = $($LocalDir + $([IO.Path]::GetFullPath($item.ServerItem.Remove(0,1)).Remove(0,3)))
        $tfsVersionControl.DownloadFile($item.ServerItem, $newFile)
    }
}
```

When I run this script it creates the folders on the drive but when it hits the part to create a new file I get this error message:

```
Exception calling "DownloadFile" with "2" argument(s): "Invalid URI: Invalid port specified."
At C:\Users\UKAutoUser\Documents\TFS_Update2.ps1:40 char:9
+         $tfsVersionControl.DownloadFile($item.ServerItem, $newFile)
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UriFormatException
```

I've tried digging through the documentation for that error but it doesnt seem to make sense. Since its connected fine as it finds the items.

Here are an example of the string values being passed into the DownloadFile method:

```
C:\Deployment\Region\Application\Master\Payments\Screens.cs
$/Region/Application/Master/Payments/Screens.cs
```

Any help would be appreciated. I seem to be almost there as I can get a list of the files which im iterating through. I just need to be able to download them to the Deployment folder.

This is so that I can later build the code using Jenkins.

Comment: Any reason why you're not using the [TFS plugin for Jenkins](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Team+Foundation+Server+Plugin)?

Comment: @JamesReed I am but it only allows you to download the source from 1 location. I need to download the sources from a few different locations.